# Minimum loss challenge

Tags: javascript

Just tried solving this hackerrank challenge (but its failing test cases 11-15 with notification Terminated due to timeout :(

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-loss/problem

I think my code is correct, but just too long (time limit?)...
Is there a way to solve this in less calculation time?

```
function minimumLoss(price) {
  let finalresult = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
  for(var i=0; i<price.length-1;i++){
    for(var j=i+1; j<price.length;j++){
      if(price[i] > price[j]){
        let subresult = price[i] - price[j]
        if(subresult < finalresult){
          finalresult = subresult
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return finalresult
}

minimumLoss([20,15,8,2,12])
minimumLoss([20,7,8,2,5])
```

Comment: Possibly suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for challenging me to solve this problem on Hackerrank, just earned 35 points :-)

[image]

Here's my solution in JavaScript

```
function minimumLoss(prices) {
    const indexes = {};
    let minLoss = Infinity;

    for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        indexes[prices[i]] = i;
    }
    const sortedPrices = Object.keys(indexes).sort((a, b) => a - b);

    for (let i = 0; i < sortedPrices.length - 1; i++) {
        if (indexes[sortedPrices[i]] > indexes[sortedPrices[i + 1]]) {
            minLoss = Math.min(minLoss, prices[indexes[sortedPrices[i + 1]]] - prices[indexes[sortedPrices[i]]]);
        }
    }
    return minLoss;
}
```

The idea here is to sort the prices and check all adjusting pairs since one of them would give the minimum loss. You have to make sure that the corresponding indexes also correct, so it takes to build a hashmap to tie an element with its index as well.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: @CharlieVdb it has O(N^2) complexity. Nothing's wrong with that if the input is small but it could be up to 2 * 10^5 elements. That's why you get a TLE error. When you sort elements and use a hashmap for indexes it's O(N * log N + N) which is less than N^2 and that's why it works fine with 2 * 10^5 elements.

Comment: In a word, it doesn't make sense to check all possible combinations of buys & sells since you know that in sorted prices minimum loss would be on neighbor's prices. So it takes to sort them first.